# tail multiple file with wildcard in AIX

Tags: wildcard, aix, tail

How to tail multiple file with wildcard in AIX?
I want to tail the multiple log files with wildcard but shows me error.
  tail -f log.*
tail: 0652-044 Can only process one file at a time.

Comment: This question seems like it might belong better on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

function finish {
  jobs -p | xargs kill
}

trap finish exit SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
for f in "$@"; do
  (tail -f "$f")&
done
wait
```